# Google advance search for a specific domain doesnt find the page which is on website

Tags: google, google-search, search-engines, search-results

I am trying to find information using Google advance search for a specific domain but its not picking up the link for keywords example (Markus Wischenbart, United Arab Emirates, Al Habtoor Group ) from above keywords its showing generic result for `Markus Wischenbart` , `United Arab Emirates` and don't show anything for  `Al Habtoor Group` following page should be picked up by google, but it doesnt show any of the link for specific domain also
[link 1](http://www.fox21delmarva.com/story/40854182/lifestyle-holidays-vacation-club-owner-president-markus-wischenbart-inks-the-biggest-recordbreaking-vacation-club-resort-deal-in-dubai-with-the-al-habtoor-group)
[link 2](https://www.lubbockcw.com/story/40854182/lifestyle-holidays-vacation-club-owner-president-markus-wischenbart-inks-the-biggest-recordbreaking-vacation-club-resort-deal-in-dubai-with-the-al-habtoor-group)

Example should show link 1 for below search result but it doesnt

Al Habtoor Group site:fox21delmarva.com

what is the possible reason for Google not to pickup these pages. is there a way i can search for these page on google. This links where picked up by other agency may be they are using some for of media monitoring tools which picked them up.